# Which is the right pronunciation of the name "Jesus" in English?

Tags: pronunciation

First of all I'm asking this question. Because, I had always pronounced the name Jesus a little different than the way I was corrected by my niece a couple days ago. Therefore, I would like to get the right way of saying this once for all.

Well here is what I had always said: "sheezus"

Here is what she told me to say: "geesoos"

Here is what I found on Cambridge Dictionary: "dʒizəs" which I think it sound close to the way I used to say it but my listening is not perfect though. ):

Ok, well. Since my first language is Spanish I looked up for the way to prounciate it in Spanish and this is what I found: "yisus" which is the same as my niece told me. Below is the link for a Yahoo answer where they say "yisus" is the right way of saying Jesus.

Link: https://espanol.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090917132259AA3ZTRO

Comment: Are you asking about the common Spanish name for an athlete or the Son of God religious name? Both of those, though spelled the same way, are pronounced differently.

Comment: Tell me both of them

Comment: BTW I know Jesus for regular people is Jesus in English and Spanish

Comment: Why do you believe that the English dictionary pronunciation is incorrect? Spanish language pronunciation is unrelated and not a question about English.

Comment: @user3169 Yeah, this is a total mess involving mixing Spanish phonology into English and asking how to untangle this. I've tried below.

Comment: The "J" is just a standard English "J" as in "Jeans" or "Jeeves", and then the word as a whole kind of rhymes with "seizes". I'm assuming here that you're talking about Jesus the Son of God.

Comment: Let me clear this out I do not believe the dictionary is wrong at all ok. It's just that I had a debate with my niece and not only her but other people because they say is "yisus" and that to me sounds totally wrong plus that's what they teach here and I want to speak correctly not like the rest of them.

Comment: Yes the son of God

Comment: In English the "J" definitely isn't pronounced as a "y", it's like the "j" in "jeans". Using a "y" is trying to mix in a Hebrew or Aramaic pronunciation from "Yeshua", which ended up as "Jesus" in English.

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know but I feel that the J in jeans sounds a lot different than the J in Jesus. If I'm wrong on this then yisus is correct as the J in Jeans sounds like Y as in Yi-ins so IDK

Comment: No, the "j" in "jeans" (as in blue denim jeans) is *not* pronounced as a "y" in English. It's like "gee". The way "Jesus" is pronounced in this video is pretty normal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzscIX9p_9o

Comment: @nnnnnn As I've said in my answer, the English J does not exist in Spanish. Their approximation is /ʝ/ or whatever their dialect makes it out to be, and in Spanish /ʝ/ is spelled as Y.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost. Yes, I have a Mexican friend who speaks very good English, but he often pronounces Js as Ys. Also the opposite: he (and other native Spanish speakers I've known) will pronounce some Ys as Js, e.g., he says the colour yellow as "jello".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> First of all I'm asking this question. Because, I had always pronounced the name Jesus a little different than the way I was corrected by my niece a couple days ago. Therefore, I would like to get the right way of saying this once for all.
>
> Well here is what I had always said: "sheezus"

Close to the English pronunciation, but the initial consonant is wrong; it is /d͡ʒ/ not your /ʃ/.

> Here is what she told me to say: "geesoos"

Is this /d͡ʒisus/? If it is, it's incorrect.

> Here is what I found on Cambridge Dictionary: "dʒizəs" which I think it sound close to the way I used to say it but my listening is not perfect though. ):

This pronunciation applies to the religious figure only.

Let's actually tackle your question:

> Ok, well. Since my first language is Spanish I looked up for the way to prounciate it in Spanish and this is what I found: "yisus" which is the same as my niece told me. Below is the link for a Yahoo answer where they say "yisus" is the right way of saying Jesus.

The problem here is that Spanish has no d͡ʒ. It does have ʝ which is spelled as Y there, hence it being transcribed "yisus". In addition, Spanish has no /z/ phoneme, hence the "s" where /z/ should go. Given your transcription of your own pronunciation, I think you already know how to make a /z/ sound.

The **schwa** (it's the U in "Jesus"), is a different problem which has been tackled to death a million times already. Just Google it.

By the way, [this is /d͡ʒ/.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palato-alveolar_affricate)

---

A big catch: The religious figure Jesus, and Spanish-speaking people named Jesus are pronounced **very differently** in English.

**Jesus of Nazareth: /d͡ʒiːzəs/**. The name of the son of God has been Anglicized.

Spanish-speaking people called Jesus: /heɪsus/. This is to approximate Spanish /xesus/.

Answer (score 0):

> Well here is what I had always said: "sheezus"
>
> Here is what she told me to say: "geesoos"

"Geezus".  "Geezus" is the pronunciation for American English (my native form), and it should be true or almost completely true for most other forms of English as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to use English or Spanish spelling to explain pronunciation of English words. Firstly English spelling is illogical and, secondly there are fewer consonants and vowels in Spanish than in English.

There are two ways forward that I am aware of

(1) Learn IPA and hence be able to accurately reproduce /dʒizəs/

(2) Hear the sound. Here's a site where you can hear jesus and other words said as in English-speaking countries around the world.

[Select the regional accent you want and click on the speaker icon](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/jesus)